# Why can't I install Eclipse?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I am trying to install Eclipse.

```
> desktop-file-install eclipse.desktop
> Error on file "eclipse.desktop": Key file does not start with a group


>Name=Eclipse 
>Type=Application
>Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
>Terminal=false
>Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
>Comment=Integrated Development Environment
>NoDisplay=false
>Categories=Development;IDE;
>Name[en]=Eclipse
```

What is wrong?
My Ubuntu version is 10.04 but I do not know if that plays any role here.

Comment: It probably does, as ubuntu 10.04 isn't supposed to be installed anywhere. Please install a [later version of the ubuntu.](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/index.html)

Answer (score 6):

You need to add

```
[Desktop Entry]
```

to the top of your file--it's the group name that command is looking for.
See [here](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/) for more information about desktop entries.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install Eclipse you only need to have a working JDK installation and the unzip the eclipse bundle and finally execute eclipse.

To install OpenJDK from ubuntu repositories you can do this.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

OpenJDK7 does not seem to be in 10.04 repositories.

You can always install [Oracle JDK](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/standard-edition/overview/index.html) manually but perhaps you should think about upgrading you ubuntu installation to the latest LTS release.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't work very well with OpenJDK. Definitely use Oracle/Sun JDK instead. And definitely install Eclipse from their web site (instead of using one of the public repos).

Answer (score -1):

Try This option.

- change permission for eclipse dir `sudo chmode -R 755 -R /opt/eclipse`.
- **Java Home**

open `gedit /home/[user]/.bashrc`
Add that two line at the end .

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk1.(xx version)

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

**Update**

- As mentioned by @Allison

  You need to add `[Desktop Entry]`

Comment: Down-vote without comment less helpful!, Please add a comment to help,